# Is is thread safe for `tf.data.Dataset.from_generator` to retrieve data from a modifiable buffer?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I want to use `tf.data.Dataset.from_generator` with a modifiable buffer such as one defined below

```py
class Buffer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.memory = np.zeros(10)

    def modify_data(self, indices, values):
        self.memory[indices] = values

    def sample(self):
        while True:
            indices = np.random.randint(0, 10, 2)
            yield self.memory[indices]

buffer = Buffer()
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    buffer.sample, output_types=tf.float32, output_shapes=(2, ))
ds = ds.prefetch(tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
```

I'm wondering if this code is thread-safe: Would `modify_data` be called at the same time `sample` yields an entry? Should I add a lock to this class if I don't explicitly use this class in a multi-threading way?

Comment: I found this question after seeing multiple threads calling my `from_generator` function when I added a downstream `map` function with a positive `num_parallel_calls`. I was looking for an answer myself, but it seems like the answer is likely no, thread safety is not guaranteed by tensorflow.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I also think so although there seems no official document mentioning that.